# Cannot add Azure Synapse Administrator despite being RBAC Owner on workspace

Tags: azure, rbac, azure-synapse

Inside the Synapse Studio Access Control page, the screen shows:

***Failed to load
Failed to load role assignments due to server error, error code 500. Refresh or troubleshoot the issue.***

[image: Issue]

As far as I can tell, no one setup the Synapse Administrator or any other roles within the studio itself.

I cannot add the Synapse Administrator. When I attempt to, I get another 500 error:

***"body": "{"error":{"code":"HttpWrapOperationAsyncFailed","message":"System.Exception : No RoleAssignment for workspace :***

I've also tried it through the CLI and got a similar error there as well.

I'm afraid that something went wrong with the deployment of the resources related to this Synapse workspace, but I don't see anything wrong within the portal. Help?

Comment: I'd raise that with Microsoft directly.

Comment: In the workspace or the Azure Portal? Can you check the permissions/settings in the Portal?

Comment: Hi, please check if your client's IP address is blocked in networking?

Comment: I did, it's not.

Comment: @CyndiJohnson Any luck with this issue?